# VS2013 Cordova project run occure XMLHttpRequest warning message?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, hybrid-mobile-app, visual-studio-cordova

VS2013 Cordova project run occure XMLHttpRequest warning message?
There's warning message as below:
"Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
File: ripple.js, Line: 50, Column: 26565"

I know the warning maybe it's okay to run on physical device, but any idea to update or upgrade to solved this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `xhr.open()`, you should set the `async` parameter to true to make the request asynchronous. Also make sure any code following the call is not dependent on any state that may be changed in the xhr callbacks.